# Not able to parse response after invoking websocket call in python-- locust

Tags: python, json, parsing, response, locust

I invoke the websocket call that returns the response that has triangle in the middle of it. I want to get rid of that triangle

Response is following :

```
{"type":1,"target":"CustomerDatapassCallback","arguments":[{"value":{"name":"PageMarkers","data":"unmarked page, unmarked page, unmarked page, unmarked page, unmarked page, unmarked page","messageId":"9E216B6458F13B9B07631F0BE2637E57"},"chatId":"36416579612304584","timestamp":-62135596800,"messageId":"9E216B6458F13B9B07631F0BE2637E57","connectionId":"l7UdY5uuw_J3jkREP42fGwfebbdf651","traceId":"a2d7f5e8-c202-4218-832b-03f7a5e36528","success":true}]}▲{"type":1,"target":"ChannelInformationCallback","arguments":[{"value":{"channel":0,"device":{"name":"Edge","version":"90.0.818.66","operatingSystem":"Windows 10"}},"chatId":"36416579612304584","timestamp":-62135596800,"messageId":null,"connectionId":"l7UdY5uuw_J3jkREP42fGwfebbdf651","traceId":"a2d7f5e8-c202-4218-832b-03f7a5e36528","success":true}]}
```

Code that I have created to overcome this issue is as follows.

```
def parse_signalr_response(json_str: str) -> List[SignalrResponse]:
```

Following code works i.e if triangle is at the end I am able to delete that triangle.

```
if (json_str.endswith('▲')):
    json_str = json_str[:(len(json_str) - Constants.sigr_suffix_decode_len)]
elif (json_str.endswith(Constants.sigr_suffix_encoded1)):
    json_str = json_str[:(len(json_str)-1)]
elif (json_str.endswith(Constants.sigr_suffix_encoded)):
    json_str = json_str[:(len(json_str)-1)]
```

Following piece of code does not work, i.e if triangle is in the middle of response. then this code does not go in the if block.

```
# if (Constants.sigr_suffix_encoded1 in json_str):
if (json_str.__contains__('▲')):
# if (json_str.find('▲')):
 
    # json_str.replace("▲", '')

base_sigr_response: SignalrResponse = JsonHelper.parse_json(json_str, SignalrResponse)

if (base_sigr_response.type == SignalrResponseType.Callback):
    return _parse_signalr_callback(json_str)

elif (base_sigr_response.type == SignalrResponseType.Response):
    if hasattr(base_sigr_response, 'error'):
        return [_parse_signalr_error(json_str)]
    else:
        return [_parse_signalr_success(json_str)]

return [base_sigr_response]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you are receiving multiple JSON objects in a single response. `▲` is where the response should be split so you can properly parse both objects.

```
import json

test_string = # Your response string
s = test_string.split('▲')
for x in s:
    j = json.loads(x)
    print(j)
```